# Как настроить файлы параметры для запуска экземпляра БД?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Моя задача - создать экземпляр БД, что я и сделал. Моя среда администрирования БД это SQL*Plus. Название экземпляра БД SID=ORCL.

Теперь мне надо его запустить, но мне для этого нужны 4 файла параметров данного экземпляра БД, соответственно:

- spfileORCL.ora
- spfile.ora
- initORCL.ora
- init.ora

При инициализации БД ORCL, файл init.ora создан, а остальные нет.

Что мне в этом случае делать по отношению к этим оставшемся трём файлам, чтобы удачно запустить БД ORCL?

Нужно их всё же создавать самостоятельно и писать вручную в них что-то ещё для настройки конфигурации внутри данных файлов, или всё же есть такая команда для SQL*Plus или SQL, которая эти 3 файла создаёт и привязывает к определённому экземпляру БД, какому я пожелаю? Если есть, то что я должен в командной строке вставить?

PS Прошу вас объяснить мне словами, а не ссылкой на docs.oracle.com, так как там тёмный лес ответы на такие вопросы искать, к сожалению.

Comment: Экземпляру нужен только один конфигурационный файл. В текущих версиях oracle он в формате spfile. Создается sql-командой `create spfile from pfile` на основе init.ora. Вы бы создавали экземпляр с помощью DBCA, потому как ручное создание подразумевает, что вы наизусть знаете все, что этого касается с docs,oracle.com. И мне сложно представить ситуацию когда бы это понадобилось

Comment: как очень правильно заметил @Mike вам достаточно и предпочтительно иметь только один конфиг. файл: `spfileORCL.ora`. Я не совсем понял вашу задачу - вы говорите, что экземпляр БД вы уже создали и у вас уже есть `spfileORCL.ora`, т.е. если ORACLE_SID='ORCL' и `spfileORCL.ora` находиться в `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/` все должно работать и так, а остальные файлы Oracle использовать не будет, если он найдет `spfileORCL.ora`. PS файлы без SID'а (spfile.ora, init.ora) вообще не нужны, разве только как примеры...

Comment: @MaxU , спасибо )). Но на всякий случай: как мне всё-таки создать правильно этот файл spfile.ora , чтобы в него было записано правильное содержимое о экземпляре БД ?

Comment: @MaxU , Или Oracle 11g spfile.ora больше не юзает ?

Comment: Если вам дали задачу создать только экземпляр БД (или то что иноземцы имнуют instance), то вы задачу выполнили. Вы создали экземпляр БД при инсталяции и можете посмотреть в init.ora - там написано, что дальше делать.

Answer (score 2):

> Теперь мне надо его запустить, но мне для этого нужны 4 файла параметров данного экземпляра БД

Экземпляру БД (*data base instance*) необходим только один файл параметров - spfileORCL.ora (бинарный), или текстовый initORCL.ora, если первый ещё не создан.

Чтобы запустить экземпляр БД, достаточно создать копию init.ora, изменить или закоментировать там пути:

```
$ export ORACLE_SID=ORCL; . oraenv; 
$ cp init.ora  initORCL.ora # edit
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup nomount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1071333376 bytes
Fixed Size                  1341312 bytes
Variable Size             620759168 bytes
Database Buffers          444596224 bytes
Redo Buffers                4636672 bytes

SQL> host ps -ef|grep pmon_ORCL
oracle    1783     1  0 16:55 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_ORCL
```

Экземпляр БД запустился успешно. Теперь можно создать БД с `CREATE DATABASE` (см. далее).

---

Следующий шаг - создать БД, описан в том же init.ora, цитирую укорочено:

> **Example INIT.ORA fil**e
> [...]
> NOTE: The values that are used in this file are only intended to be used
> as a starting point. [...]
> You may also **consider using Database Configuration Assistant tool (DBCA)** to create INIT file and to size your initial set of tablespaces based on the user input.

То есть, далее следует воспользоваться програмой DBCA для создания БД. Она выполнит всю необходимую работу, включая `CREATE DATABASE`. Файл параметров spfileORCL.ora будет создан при этом автоматически.

PS DBCA лучше запускать без GUI (*silent mode*), например, по [этому мануалу](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/database-configuration-assistant-dbca-silent-mode).